# Summing the first $n$-terms of the series whose general term is $nx^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, geometric-progressions, reference-works

I suppose several of you know some fancy ways to establish the formula for the sum of the first $n$ terms of the geometric series $$1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+ \ldots $$

**Can you share below some of your fave ways to sum the first** $n$ **terms of the series**
$$ 1 + 2x+ 3x^{2} + \ldots $$

Naturally,  for $x \neq 1$, one way to attain the goal is to take the derivative of both sides of $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} = \frac{x^{n}-1}{x-1}.$$

Another possibility is to apply something that the authors of certain handbook of discrete and  combinatorial math called "the perturbation method": if $S(n):= \sum_{k=1}^{n} kx^{k-1}$, then

$$ S(n) + (n+1)x^{n} = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} kx^{k-1}$$

which can be rewritten as

$$ S(n) + (n+1)x^{n} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)x^{k}.$$

Thus,

$$ (1-x)S(n) = \frac{x(x^{n}-1)}{x-1} + 1 - (n+1)x^{n}$$

or

$$S(n) = \frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}{(x-1)^{2}}.$$

What other cool ways to sum $1+2x+ \cdots + nx^{n-1}$ do you know or have heard of? **Have you ever seen a "proof without words" of the result in question?**

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: This is [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence)

Comment: It is just the derivative of $\sum_{m=0}^n x^m$.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that above...

Comment: If you directly multiply $(1-x)^2 S(n) = (1-2x+x^2) S(n)$, most terms are of the form $(k+1) x^k - 2x \cdot k x^{k-1} + x^2 \cdot (k-1) x^{k-2} = 0$.  All you're left with is the exceptional terms near the beginning and end.

Answer (score 3):

$1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots + nx^{n-1}$

= $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} $

$+ x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} $

$+ x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} $

$+ \cdots + x^{n-1}$

$= \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

$+\dfrac{x^n-x}{x-1}$

$+\dfrac{x^n-x^2}{x-1}$

$+\cdots + \dfrac{x^{n}-x^{n-1}}{x-1}$

$=\dfrac{nx^n-(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})}{x-1}$

$=\dfrac{nx^n-\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}}{x-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer... I did not mention this approach in my question, but I sort of had it in mind at the time of composing the thread.